# set new relationship and save previous relationship as old relationship in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I’m trying to transfer data from sql database to neo4j.
I have created company nodes, number nodes and relationship between them in neo4j.

```
(n:company{un_id:’11111’})-[r:using]->(m:phonenumber{N:‘555112233’})
```

Sometimes, companies are changing its number and I want to set new relationship like

```
Match
(n:company{un_id:’11111’}),
(m:phonenumber{N:‘555445566’})
Merge
(n)-[r:using]->(m)
Return id(r)
```

So if there is no more relationship between company and old phone number, how can I set previous relationship as old rel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `status` property on the relationship could help you, for instance like this

```
WITH '555445566' AS newNumber,
       '11111' AS companyID

//set existing r.status to 'old'
MATCH (n:company {un_id:companyID})-[r:using]->(ph:phonenumber)
WHERE ph.N <> newNumber AND r.status <> 'old'
SET r.status = 'old'

// make sure to remove duplicates in case previous statement returns multiples
WITH DISTINCT newNumber, n

// create the new rel
MERGE (newph:phonenumber {N:newNumber})
MERGE (n)-[r:using {status:'current'}]->(newph) 
RETURN id(r)
```

Comment: is there operator like 'didnot match'?

Comment: thank you for your support, and great answer,
is there operator like 'not match'? because in db there is a lot of phone numbers and i don't now which one is new like
'
match
(n), (m)
merge 
(n)-[r:using]->(m)
on create
set (n)-[r:using]->(m)
on not mutch
set r as old r
'